# Opencv python camera calibration : objp matrix

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, camera-calibration

This is the camera calibration code as on the opencv python docs. I want to know how objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2) works. What does reshape (-1,2) do? I tried to change the values in this line of code but got errors. Can someone explain how this works and why only these numbers would work?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
print "objp: ",objp
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

print "objp: ",objp
# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('left*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        # Draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None) # camera matrix, distortion coefficients, rotation and translation vectors
```

Also, objpoints are 3D real world coordinates. This should be manually measured right? Why do we assign points from (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)??
Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post the error code and the exception, so we can help you to fix it.

-1 mean calculate the real length from the total element number:

```
np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

you can split the code as following:

```
a = np.mgrid[0:7, 0:6]
b = a.T
c = b.reshape(-1, 2)

print a.shape, b.shape, c.shape
```

the output is:

```
(2, 7, 6) (6, 7, 2) (42, 2)
```

if it's difficult to understand the code it's the same as:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[0:7, 0:6]
np.c_[x.ravel(), y.ravel()]
```

objpoints are 3D real world coordinates, but the length unit is arbitrary, so you don't need to manually measure it if all the box has the same edge length. If the length of the edge is 16cm, then one in `objp` means 16cm.